# android keyboard focus

Tags: java, android, focus

I would like to perform a action when an object comes into focus but only if it happens because of the hardware directional pad and not touch events. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to override the [onKeyDownEvent method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) in your view or activity. The method is passed a keyCode and a KeyEvent object. Check to see if it was the directional pad. For example (in your `View` or `Activity` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEY_DPAD_UP) {
        // do you stuff here
    }
}
```

Of course you can check for other codes and use a nested if or switch statement to handle several different keyCodes.